# Will the $output parameter passed in the exec report all the PHP errors generated during the execution of the command?

Tags: php, linux

```
for($i=0;$i<=$var;$i++)
{

   $argv1=$i*$countind;
   $argv2=($i*$countind)+$countind;

 exec("php /home/indiamart/public_html/prod-clickstream/cron/EmailMarketing.php $argv1 $argv2 $mon $week_hour > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!",$output);
 sleep(2);  
 $mon++;   

}
```

Above Code Run on:

```
Linux Server-[Apache with PHP 5 installed].
```

In the above code,I am running a command`[php /home/indiamart/public_html/prod-clickstream/cron/EmailMarketing.php $argv1 $argv2 $mon $week_hour > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!]` to execute the code written in the file(/home/indiamart/public_html/prod-clickstream/cron/EmailMarketing.php).

The Output from the above code open several threads(based upon the number of iteration of for loop).Below is the sample output.

```
php /home/indiamart/public_html/prod-clickstream/cron/EmailMarketing.php 0 10000 1 12

php /home/indiamart/public_html/prod-clickstream/cron/EmailMarketing.php 10000 20000 1 12

php /home/indiamart/public_html/prod-clickstream/cron/EmailMarketing.php 20000 30000 1 12
```

My concern is that if suppose x threads are opened out of which only y completed successfully.
 How to track the PHP Error or the reason for the threads which didn't execute successfully(x-y)?

Comment: Please explain your problem in details .

Comment: hi @hollopost,I have tried to explain it in detail now.Kindly help